# Shotgun on boom or handheld?

Tags: microphone, boom-pole

What's the benefits of using your shotgun on a boom pole instead of just holding it in your hands? As I see many people use the boom from above, why isn't it better to position the microphone at mouth level with your bare hands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main point of having a handheld or boom mic is to keep it away from the face.

When filming, your focus is on the individual, so usually a shot will have face, or head, or head and shoulders, or head and torso - so you will see that the camera tends to not go above the head but can capture a lot of below-the-head images. So a mic above the head is less likely to end up in shot.

You also get the added benefit that a boom operator can position the mic appropriately - and a good operator will have a much better idea of where to position it than most people do.

Comment: Yes, but I mean in filming a movie. Why do you need a boom instead of just holding the microphone? For example a guy standing next to the camera witth the microphone.

Comment: You mean pointing the mic from the distance the camera is? Sound quality is they key here. The closer you can get it, the greater the difference between signal and noise floor.